# Rendering Custom View in SuiteCRM not working

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have a controller that calls my custom view, but the custom view is not getting rendered.
I cant understand the issue, everything looks correct to me.
Neither is it displaying any errors or warnings.

My module name is SCRV_SSRS_CRM_Reports_View

I have below code in:

> custom/modules/SCRV_SSRS_CRM_Reports_View/controller.php

```
require_once('include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php');

class SCRV_SSRS_CRM_Reports_ViewController extends SugarController
{
    function action_test(){
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('Am in Controller');
        $this->view = "test";
    }
}
```

And in

> custom/modules/SCRV_SSRS_CRM_Reports_View/views/view.test.php

```
if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php');

class SCRV_SSRS_CRM_Reports_ViewViewtest extends ViewList
{

    public function display()
    {
        echo "HIIII";
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('Am in View');
    }
}
```

Cant see the view getting rendered when I access it by

> http://localhost:8080/dev-crm/index.php?module=SCRV_SSRS_CRM_Reports_View&action=test

I cant see HIIII displayed on screen or the log entry.

Comment: Hi, Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Have you run a repair?

Comment: Are you at least seeing the "Am in controller" message in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

Controller should be

```
class CustomMeetingsController extends SugarController {
     $this->view = 'invite';
}
```

and View should be like

```
class CustomMeetingsViewinvite extends ViewList {
     public function display() {
        echo 'hiiiii';
     }
}
```